# Crystal reports display a blank page in C#, asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I have a website in vs2008. I have created a crystal report which works fine in the DEVELOPMENT environment. But when I publish my website to IIS, the report is never displayed. It just displays a blank page. Can anyone tell me how to resolve this issue?
Thanks

Comment: can you show some markup of the page? Are you sure the server has all required components? CR is really a pain about deployment of all required components.

Comment: aro you using Default website? I suppose you aren't...

Answer (score 8):

If you installed your application in a website different from `Default WebSite`, try this:

#### Solution

- Copy `aspnet_client` folder from `c:\inetpub\wwwroot` folder to the new website root folder.

or in IIS:

- Create a virtual directory called `aspnet_client` that points to `c:\inetpub\wwwroot` *inside the new website*.

#### Cause of the problem

Using client tools (debug window of your browser) or server tool (IIS log) you will find that some required Crystal files like `crv.js` and `style.css`  are not served.  That's because these files are placed by CR installer in `wwwroot\aspnet_client` folder, but they cannot be reached from other websites installed on the same machine.

I can see that you use different versions of software and different configurations, but I think you have the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure Folder "2_0_50727" exists at C:\inetpub\wwwroot\aspnet_client\system_web 
or your SiteRootFolder\aspnet_client\system_web

if not exists copy the folder "4_0_30319" as "2_0_50727".

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Submit button for viewing the report, make sure you effect a full postback on submit button click. You will find that all pages in the report will work perfectly fine.

Note: Use Trigger with Update Panel to Effect the Full Post Back (The Control ID of the trigger should be the ID of the button).

Answer (score 1):

Perfect! The solution is to work on IIS this way:

- Copy aspnet_client folder from c:\inetpub\wwwroot folder to the new website root folder.

***OR***

- Create a virtual directory called aspnet_client that points to c:\inetpub\wwwroot inside the new website

Thank you so much

Comment: why did you copy my solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the merge modules on the web server.  You can download them from [Here](http://resources.businessobjects.com/support/additional_downloads/runtime.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Check the Crystal Report Run-time version, for example if you install version 13.0.1 and your Visual Studio uses 13.0.2 the report will display but not data will be displayed.